# Python - how to add initial MP3 attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, mp3

I used to get songs with the artist and  the song name in the file name (for example - "britney spears - oops i did it again".
My script have 2 purposes:
1.add the artist name and song to his MP3's attributes (Using eyed3).
2.create a new folder to the artist in my main music folder (if I already don't have one).

My problem is that if the MP3 file have no attributes, I can't add it new ones..

Here is my code (It's my first one :-))..Thanks!

```
#That's the 0.2 ver of my code
import os
import shutil
import eyed3.id3

songs_path = raw_input("Please insert the path of your Songs: ")
music_path = raw_input("Please insert the path of your music folders location: ")

#That's function supposed to present the files in a path
def files_in_folder(m):
    Files = os.listdir(m)
    return Files

mp3_files_list = files_in_folder(downloads_path)
artist_list = files_in_folder(music_path)

for i in mp3_files_list:
    song_artist, song_title = i.split(' - ')
    if not os.path.exists(music_path + '\\' + song_artist):
        os.mkdir(music_path + '\\' + song_artist, 0777 )
    src_file = os.path.join(downloads_path, i)
    dst_file = os.path.join(music_path + '\\' + song_artist + '\\' + song_title)
    print src_file
    print dst_file
    shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
    track_mp3_file = eyed3.load(dst_file)
    if track_mp3_file.tag is None:
        track_mp3_file.tag = eyed3.id3.Tag()
        track_mp3_file.tag.file_info = eyed3.id3.FileInfo(dst_file)
    track_mp3_file.tag.artist = unicode(song_artist, "UTF-8")
    print track_mp3_file.tag.artist
    track_mp3_file.tag.title = unicode(song_title, "UTF-8")
    track_mp3_file.tag.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

try to save the tag with another id3 version:

`track_mp3_file.tag.save(version=(2, 3, 0))`

from wikipedia:

> Windows Explorer and Windows Media Player cannot handle ID3v2.4 tags
>   in any version, up to and including Windows 8 / Windows Media Player
>   12. Windows can understand ID3v2 up to and including version 2.3